# Javascript function to pass product ID into Facebook pixel event

Tags: javascript, facebook, variables, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get the dynamic retargeting ads on Facebook working. I need to pass the product ID value into the "add to cart" pixel event to properly associate relevant products in the ads.

On the product pages, the ID appears in the URL, so I created a variable to pull the ID using this:

```
function () {
  var urlPart = document.location.pathname.split('/')[3]; 
  return urlPart;
}
```

However, for the "add to cart" event, the product ID is only available in the  link.

Example:

```
<a href="/cart/add/AA1257" class="btn-add-cart btn btn-primary btnblock">Add to Cart</a>
```

Where "AA1257" is the product ID.

So my question is, **how can I create a variable in Google Tag Manager that pulls that product ID value from the href?** I'm a complete .js noob so go easy on me :)

I tried creating something like this to pull the href but I'm lost after that...

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-add-cart").getAttribute("href");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for asking your first question on stackoverflow! Does your <script> have a line break after `"btn-add-`? If so, trying making that one line like `document.getElementsByClassName("btn-add-cart").getAttribute("href")`. Does that help?

Comment: No line break, that was my bad on formatting.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, you need to access individual elements via index to be able to access their properties.

Comment: _“but I'm lost after that...”_ - once you got the reference to the link element, you can access parts of the URL it links to the same way you can access them with the location object, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils `document.querySelector('.btn-add-cart').pathname` would get you access to the path part of the URL the first link with that class in the document links to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather you need the product ID when the add to cart button is clicked, so you do not need custom HTML to get the href - if you have enabled the built-in click variables GTM will give you this for free as {{Click URL}} (if the links includes any markup, like span-elements around the text, you should use a "just links" click trigger else this might not work).

Like before you can then split the variable and get the last element:

```
elementAfterLastSlash = {{Click URL}}.split("/").pop();
```

(split creates an array by delimiter, pop removes and returns the last element).

Comment: Thanks Eike. That makes sense.

Comment: If that helped then you can click the checkmark next to my answer - that gives me a few points in "reputation" and removes the question from the "unanswered questions" list.